# How do I recover a ZIP file in WinRAR that's inside of another RAR file?

Tags: zip, archiving, file-corruption, rar, winrar

I tried to use WinRAR to extract an archive, but I couldn't extract all of it because of 1 thing: a file inside the archive was corrupt. I tried using `Alt+R`, but it tried to do it to the entire archive, which I don't want. It also tried to get me to open another file to fix it. What other file? I am so confused! Please help!

Comment: Why don't you want to repair the entire archive? Also are you able to download another copy of the file?

Comment: I don't want to repair the entire archive because all the other parts are fine; it's just that one. And no, I am not able to download another copy. :/

Answer (score 1):

Just right click on the winrar archieve and click extract files.Then in the box there will be a miscellaneous option (Keep Broken Files). Just check the box and extract it into your directory..